# Pyneo Inserts Limited Amount of Edges

Tags: python, neo4j

For a university project I am using Neo4j together with flask and pyneo for a shift scheduling algorithm. On saving the scheduled shifts to Neo4j I realized that relationships go missing, from 330 only 91 get inserted.

On printing them before/after inserting, they are in the list to be inserted, and I also moved the transaction around to check if this changes the result.

I have the following structure:
(w:Worker)-[r:works_during]->(s:Shift) with
r.day, r.month, r.year as set parameters for the relationship and multiple connections between each worker and each shift, which can be filtered via the relation then.

my code looks like the following:

```
    header = df.columns.tolist()
    header.remove("index")
    header.remove("worker")
    tuplelist = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for i in header:
            worker = self.driver.nodes.match("Worker", id=int(row["worker"])).first()
            if row[i] == 1:
                # Shifts are in the format {day}_{shift_of_day}
                shift_id = str(i).split("_")[1]
                shift_day = str(i).split("_")[0]
                shift = self.driver.nodes.match("Shift", id=int(shift_id)).first()
                rel = Relationship(worker, "works_during", shift)
                rel["day"] = int(shift_day)
                rel["month"] = int(month)
                rel["year"] = int(year)
                tuplelist.append(rel)
    print(len(tuplelist))

    for i in tuplelist:
        connection = self.driver.begin()
        connection.create(i)
        connection.commit()
```

Is there any special behaviour in pyneo which I need to be aware of that could cause this issue?

Comment: Probably they are not lost just not displayed in Neo4j desktop? Did you try to match them all with some `MATCH ... RETURN count(...)` command to ensure that they really don't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Pyneo allows just one connection from the same type between node A and node B.
If multiple connections of the same type (even with different attributes) are needed, it is necessary to use plain Cypher Querying as pyneo will merge this edges to a single edge.